# ActionCable and Heroku Redis configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, heroku-redis

Last week RedisToGo was terminated on Herokum, leaving me with no choice but to find an alternative. I got a new subscription from Heroku: Heroku Redis.

Everything seems to work fine (all tasks/jobs) except things related to ActionCable.

```
[ActionCable] [#######] Registered connection (#########)
2022-08-17T00:40:23.213184+00:00 app[web.1]: #<Thread:0x00007e#####@/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actioncable-5.1.7/lib/action_cable/subscription_adapter/redis.rb:144 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
2022-08-17T00:40:23.213206+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/redis-4.1.4/lib/redis/client.rb:268:in `rescue in io': Connection lost (ECONNRESET) (Redis::ConnectionError)
```

I spent the last few days trying all sort of trick, but nothing work.
My `cable.yml` file looks like:

```
production:
  adapter: redis
  url: <%= ENV['REDIS_URL'] %>
```

my `redis.rb` file looks like this:

```
uri = if Rails.env == 'production'
        URI.parse(ENV["REDIS_URL"])
      else
        URI.parse("redis://localhost:6379")
      end
Resque.redis = Redis.new(host: uri.host, port: uri.port, password: uri.password, ssl_params: { verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE })
```

Am I missing certain parameters that results in the error ?

Comment: Do any of your tasks and jobs use Redis? Or is ActionCable the only thing using Redis?

Comment: hey, yes the tasks use Redis as well, yes.

Comment: Try using the `ssl_params`, if that fails, see the two links to at the end, especially if you're on Rails 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Heroku Redis and here's what my `cable.yml` looks like:

```yaml
development:
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://localhost:6379/1
  channel_prefix: myapp_development

test:
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://localhost:6379/1
  channel_prefix: myapp_test

production:
  adapter: redis
  url: <%= ENV.fetch("REDIS_URL") { "redis://localhost:6379/1" } %>
  channel_prefix: myapp_production
  ssl_params:
      verify_mode: <%= OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE %>
```

If your tasks and jobs don't use Redis (if ActionCable is the only thing trying to use Redis) then your Redis might not actually be set up properly. [Here's the documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-redis#provisioning-the-add-on).

1. Check to make sure Heroku actually set a `REDIS_URL` env variable:

```bash
$ heroku config | grep REDIS
> REDIS_URL: redis://h:asdfqwer1234asdf@ec2-111-1-1-1.compute-1.amazonaws.com:111
```

2. Make sure your instance has a normal configuration:
   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-redis#configuring-your-instance

Two other helpful sources:

- [How to solve the SSL error for Redis 6 on Heroku](https://ogirginc.github.io/en/heroku-redis-ssl-error)
- [ActionCable Redis adapter crashes with Heroku Redis 6](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/42036)

Comment: Thank you , i followed your code and ActionCable is back to work. But now, the email Deliver_later method which used to be fine, no longer works. On heroku, Redis is trying to connect to localhost: Redis::CannotConnectError (Error connecting to Redis on localhost:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)):

Comment: You say `localhost`, is this in test or development? Can you confirm redis is using port 6379?

Comment: Hey, i did some more research and few people reported this problem. What i ended up doing that works is: $redis = Resque.redis = Redis.new(url: uri, ssl_params: { verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE })
 in redis.rb file. Now it all works. Thank you !!!!